# Subversion hooks in config folder

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

I want to enable the users of my SVN repository to edit the commit messages, but I only have access to the .subversion directory.

Inside this directory there is a auth directory, a config and servers file and a README.txt (which don't have instructions for hooks).

I read that I need to add a file to the hooks folder but I can't access it.

Is there a way to create hooks adding a file or script in this .subversion directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.subversion` directory is found in each user's home directory after executing a Subversion client once. It stores that user's configuration settings for their client, and nothing more. What you find here has absolutely no effect on server configuration.

Hook scripts must be installed into the `hooks` directory of the repository itself - you need to have some level of administrative access to the server to do this.

See also http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks

Comment: I thought something similar, just wanted to confirm it. Thanks.

Comment: A slight clarification here: adding hooks folder into the repository locally and committing it does not work of course. You have to work directly on the SVN server and go the filesystem folder for the repository. There you can find/place all the repository metadata or config.